# How to merge two Datatables with different columns and row count

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable

Hi I have two datatables dtMain and dtSub
i use .merge function and came up with this result
[image]

I was looking for ways to merge it like this
[image]

is there a way to merge two different datables?

Comment: A simple way would be to loop[ though each dataset you want to add to the original, adding each column as a new column in the original. I am sure there might be some simpler functions that does it, but if you are looking for a solution that would help.

Comment: Do your Tables have a PrimaryKey that determine a relation between their Rows? Yes? Then you can use it to merge the Tables, since the Rows in one Table can find a matching Row in the other. No? What is then the relation between the Rows of the two Tables? -- You need to post the structure of your Tables, possibly describe why this cannot be done with a query, assuming the data come from a database. Otherwise, what is the source of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Think you'll need to roll your own for this:

```
for(int m = 0; m<dtSub.Rows.Count; m++){
  foreach(var c in dtSub.Columns){
    if(!dtMain.Columns.Contains(c.ColumnName))
      dtMain.Columns.Add(c.ColumnName);

    dtMain.Rows[m][c.ColumnName] = dtSub.Rows[m][c.ColumnName];
  }
}
```